# Crashing at checkInoutAndNativeTypeCheckedBounds

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, enumerate, indexoutofrangeexception

My code looks like this -

```
func addAfterDeletingPrexisting(type: InsightType, value: [String: Any]) {
    arrayUpdationQueue.sync {
       let insightsLocal = insights
       var outputInsights = insights
       for (offset: index, element: (key: key, value: _)) in insightsLocal.enumerated() {
           if key == type {
               outputInsights.remove(at: index) // Crashes here
           }
       }
       insights = outputInsights
       self.insights.append((key: type, value: value))
   }
}
```

And my code is crashing randomly saying

> Swift._ArrayBuffer._checkInoutAndNativeTypeCheckedBounds (Swift.Int,
>   wasNativeTypeChecked : Swift.Bool) -> ():

On console when I print `index` then I get this weird result-

```
(lldb) po index
(Function)
```

What am I doing wrong? I understand that crash is due to index not being Int. I have a doubt, is crash due to different queue editing array, but for that only I was using `queue.sync`.

Comment: Can there be multiple items with key == type in insightsLocal?

Comment: Yes, there can be.

Comment: Then it can be a reason for crash. Let's suppose you have list of [1,2,2] and want to  delete '2' items. 
You'll first delete item at index 1 and now you have only [1,2].
Now you have index == 2 and are trying to delete it, but outputInsights only have 2 items => crash.

Comment: To avoid such crash only I have used two variables.

Comment: I know, there can be better ways to do the same thing, but I was curious about why the debugger is calling that index as Function.

Comment: Don't know as for the type. But the using 2 arrays won't resolve the crash (so, indeed it's hapenning). If you need to remove specific items from Array you can use `filter` function like

Comment: Yes I had solved in similar way, anyways thanks @Krizai. :)